# How To Disable "Restore Down" In .NET MAUI Blazor Component App

Tags: .net, maui, blazor-webassembly, maui-blazor

I have created one .NET MAUI Blazor Component App.

I want to restrict user to not to restore down the window.
Simply, I want to disable below button in `Windows` as well as `MAC Catalyst`.

[image]

Also I want to force application to open it in maximized window for `Windows` & `MAC Catalyst`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the window maximize and then disable the maximize button on both Windows and MAC Catalyst platform?

Comment: @Guangyu Bai - MSFT
Yes, That's correct. I want to force my app to open in maximized window and then disable maximize/restore down button (As shown in above image).

Comment: You can try the code I posted in the answer. It works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below in the `MauiProgram.cs`. It can disable the maximize button on the windows platform and make the window maximize.

```
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            // Make sure to add "using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;" in the top of the file
            events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
            {
                windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;
                    var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
                    var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
                    switch (appWindow.Presenter)
                    {
                        case Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:
                            overlappedPresenter.Maximize();
                            overlappedPresenter.IsMaximizable = false;
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
#endif
```

Comment: This solution worked to force application maximize window in Windows. What about MAC catalyst & What about disabling/hide maximize/restore down buttons in windows & MAC catalyst.

Comment: The Maximize button has been disabled by using `overlappedPresenter.IsMaximizable = false;` on the windows platform.